# How to change the font size of all pages using the Range in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following html code [settings.html]

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-range min="1" max="4" snaps="true" [(ngModel)]="fontSize" class="fontSize">
        <ion-label range-left style="font-size: 12px;">A</ion-label>
        <ion-label range-right style="font-size: 20px;">A</ion-label>
      </ion-range>
</ion-item>
<p class="fontSize" [ngClass]="{xs: fontSize===1, sm: fontSize===2, md: fontSize===3, lg: fontSize===4}">Teste</p>
```

How do I change the font size of all pages dynamically by dragging the range?
I was able to make fonts change on the settings.html page, but I have no idea how to do this to modify the font size of all pages.

The result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZeU9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Slider Input control, you can get the Font Size Value. You can define the default Font-Size property in body tag. When user changes you can access the body html element using 'document.getElementByTagName' and assign the font-size using setAttribute property.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tsusob

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code on stackblitz.
You can take a look at here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nrqrwr?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html